# GotW advices no public virtual functions, but what about interfaces ala Java?

Tags: c++, virtual

According to Herb Sutter, http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm recommends you don't have any public virtual functions but instead calls private virtual functions from non-virtual public functions. I get the gist of it, where if you want something done in the base class it cannot be done if it's put in a virtual function a derived class overrides. But what about pure interfaces, is that really so bad? Specifically I'm talking about the exposed classes from a library. Take the observer pattern:

```
class Observer {
    public:
        virtual ~Observer() = default;

        virtual void notify() = 0;
};
```

vs

```
class Observer {
    public:
        virtual ~Observer() = default;

        void notify() { doNotify() };

    protected:
        virtual void doNotify() = 0;
};
```

Is the latter really the one we're supposed to use? I just don't see the gain. Or is the specific post from Herb Sutter simply out dated?

Comment: yes, the latter one is the one you should use. It allows the base class to take care of mutexes, logging, bookeeping, etc etc

Comment: The "want something done in the base class" cannot apply to interfaces. Interfaces do nothing.

Comment: I actually changed my answer from a more complex example since I thought it detracted from the pure interface question. But since you mention mutexes I'll ask here. Say you have the other side of the observer pattern, the caller. You need to implement this thread safe, but I STILL want to encapsulate as much implementation as possible. Why not keep a pure virtual interface `WorkInterface` and have an abstract class `WorkAbstract` derive the `addObserver(Observer *)` method with the respective mutex and other details and then finally have the `ConcreteWork` inherit that? Full encapsulation.

Comment: Personally I use the NVI pattern only in abstract base classes and not in pure interfaces. If something needs to be done in the implementation, I would create an AbstractObserver implementation that declares notify "final" and calls the pure virtual doNotify

Comment: What does the separation between WorkAbstract and WorkInterface achieve?

Comment: It hides the implementation details (e.g. private mutex member) from the user. Or am I simply too focused on hiding details?

Comment: @martin "Abstract" prolly is a poor term if the class does something specific like locking a mutex. Call it FilteringObserver or something. You will keep the inferface just clean and won't commit to any behavior. Why not keep the option of a non-filtering observer open?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb .  Why not?  YAGNI.  Interfaces *have* to commit to behaviour.  That's what an interface is - a commitment to a certain behaviour.

Comment: @MartinBonner well not that sort of observable behavior. What I meant by "behavior" was non-observable behavior (regarding the observers at the user side) like locking a mutex. Threadsafety can be achieved differently aswell, and this can affect the implementations's behavior in terms of what observers perceive on the implementation's side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that "Pure Interfaces" are needed in Java because you can only inherit from one class that is not a Pure Interface in Java (this does have the advantage of preventing diamond inheritance, so avoiding any problems with it).  In C++ we can inherit from multiple base classes, and so there is no need for an interface to be pure.

In the particular case of Observer, where the base class is just a cheap way of providing a member function pointer to a single member, the advice probably doesn't apply.  (In modern C++ one would not probably not implement Observer with a base class at all, but with a std::function which could be a lambda, or a bound function, or whatever.)